# Java operating long numbers

Tags: java, numbers, long-integer, operation

Have been doing a mathematic example in java which would find all numbers between number1 and number2(including number1 and number2) that divide numbers 2 ,3 or 5. I don't need all those numbers, just how many numbers there are.

So for example if inputing 10 and 100 it will return 67.
Done with for statement and one if with or signs in it.

This is done great for smaller numbers, but I need to use type "long"(variables must be this type!) and numbers up to 18 digits.

So when having numbers: 123456789123456789 and 989898989898989898 the for statement isn't good because it takes to much time. Is there some better solution for this, a quicker one?

Comment: You haven't even shown us your solution, so how can we say if there's a better one?

Comment: As said now a have a for staement taht goes from number1 to number2, checks all numbers between if they are diveded with 2,3 or 5. But if using thoose big numbers, it takes ages, so I guess a for statement isnt good?

Answer (score 0):

this is the only way i think

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    long a = 111111111111111111l;
    long b = 111111111111115000l;       
    int match = 0;
    for (long i=a; i!=b; i++)
    {
        if( ((i % 2) == 0) && ((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0) )
            match++;
    }
    System.out.println(match);
}
```

it will always take too much time because hee's done n(b-a) cycle...